# returning a value from a column if row number equals to a given value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns, let's call them "value" and "diff". The column diff contains random row numbers.
I would like to create a vector by selecting values from the column "value" satisfying one condition, namely finding the value where the number given in diff column equals to the rownumber of the dataframe.
Shall I try it with a for loop, or is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to have sample data and your efforts so far, but since this seems very basic, here what I think you mean:

```
# crate a simple data frame along the lines of your question
x <- data.frame( value = c( 1,3,5,7,9 ), diff = c( 2, 1, 3, 9, 5 ) )
> x
  value diff
1     1    2
2     3    1
3     5    3
4     7    9
5     9    5

# select records where the row name ( = row number ) of the data frame
> x[ rownames( x ) == x$diff, ]
  value diff
3     5    3
5     9    5
```

No loop or other tools needed, simple R subsetting.

EDIT - pls check whether this is a correct understanding of your question and whether the outcome is what you expect:

```
x <- data.frame( value = c( 1,3,5,7,9 ), diff = c( 2, 1, 5, 3, 4 ) )
> x[ x$diff, 2 ]
[1] 1 2 4 5 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, probably I was not clear enough. I am not interested in a subset. Using your reply I would need to know for every row the value for diff equaling the row number, like this
1/1/2 - 3
2/3/1 - 1
so in the first row the diff value is 2 and I need the value from the second row (3), in the second row the diff value is 1 and I need the value from the first row (1)

Comment: this is what I have so far:

    thres <- vector()
    for (i in seq_along(row.names(dataframe))) {
     thres[i] <- dataframe[dataframe$diff=row.names(dataframe)[i], 1]
    }
    thres

for some reason it does not work

Comment: `x[ x$diff, "diff" ]`